# what does the <fieldset> node mean in config.xml of a payment module?

Tags: magento-1, configuration, xml

I'm trying to learn custom payment modules creation, but I can't really understand what does the node:

```
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_payment>
            <custom_field_one>
                <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
            </custom_field_one>
            <custom_field_two>
                <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
            </custom_field_two>
        </sales_convert_quote_payment>
    </fieldsets>
```

mean.. can anyone explain this please?

The descriptions says:

save custom fields related to our custom payment method during the order creation.

But need tag by tag description if possible.

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit of context to the good answers already provided...

So the fieldsets are used to transfer data from an object to an other in an easy and flexible way.
The method that uses the fieldsets is `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::copyFieldset` that has this signature:

```
public function copyFieldset($fieldset, $aspect, $source, $target, $root='global')
```

the first 2 parameters represent the name of the fieldset to be transfered (`sales_convert_quote_payment` in your example) and `$aspect` is what is copied to. (`to_order_payment` in your example).
The third and 4th parameter are the source (the object that provides data) and the destination (object that should receive data).
And here is how it works.
The method loops through all the child node of the fieldset (`custom_field_one` and `custom_field_two` in your example), checks of each child node has a child called the same as the `aspect` parameter and if it does it transfers the data from the source to the destination for that field.
The 5th parameter is to tell magento in which are to look for the specific `fieldset`, By default it looks inside the `global` tag of the config.

```
       <custom_field_one>
            <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
        </custom_field_one>
```

is the equivalent of

```
$destination->setCustomFieldOne($source->getCustomFieldOne());
```

if you call the method like this

```
Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset('sales_convert_quote_payment', 'to_order_payment', $source, $destination);
```

the * in `<to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>` means that the field name on the destination matches the field name on the source.
If you were to change the line mentioned above to `<to_order_payment>some_other_field</to_order_payment>`, this will be equivalent to

```
$destination->setSomeOtherField($source->getCustomFieldOne());
```

How is this useful?
If for example you want to clone an other field from the quote to the payment object you just need to add this in your own module inside `config.xml`

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote_payment>
        <my_field>
            <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
        </my_field>
    </sales_convert_quote_payment>
</fieldsets>
```

and create the column in the payments table and it will all be transferred automatically, You don't need code that contains logic in order to do it.

Comment: Great exploration.

Answer (score 1):

The `<fieldsets>` tag is mainly used to define which fields (attributes) are to be copied to where while converting objects, e.g. in a quote to order conversion.

Magento source for `Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset()` occurrences to see how the real copy processes look like.

Answer (score 0):

This tells magento that your custom payment field  **custom_field_one** and  **custom_field_two** values are transferred from **quote object** to **order object** automatically during order place